# スクレイピングで特定のページに直接アクセスした場合にエラーで弾かれてしまう場合の対処方法は？

Tags: python, web-scraping

PythonでJRAのページから馬柱をスクレイピングしようとしています。

```py
>>> url ='http://www.jra.go.jp/JRADB/accessD.html'
>>> fetched_dataframes = pandas.io.html.read_html(url)
>>> fetched_dataframes[0]
```

コマンドとしては上記のような内容でスクレイピングを実践しており、他のサイトでは表をスクレイピングできましたが、JRAのページに関しては「パラメータエラー ご指定のページに接続できませんでした。」とエラーになってしまいます。

googleでも調べてみたのですが同様のケースが見当たらず、もし原因や対策などをご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教示いただけますでしょうか。

ご回答お待ちしております。

Comment: ブラウザでアクセスしても「パラメータエラー」のページが表示されます。期待している内容や、うまくいくURLを提示されてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: トップページから「出馬表」のリンクをクリックした場合に出来るURLみたいですね。要するに POSTデータで表示内容を決定している（にも関わらずURLも適当かつPOSTデータ無しでは無効な物に変更しているという謎設計）という事ですね。

Comment: 設計意図は謎ですが、コードはきれいなので読めばすぐ理解出来ると思います。

Answer (score 0):

selenium(webdriver)を使い、トップページ（http://www.jra.go.jp/）から「出馬表」リンクをクリックし、該当ページに移動すれば、スクレイピング可能です。